# Cómo usar correctamente el Delete en VBA - Actualizado

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo la siguiente función que debe eliminar todos las filas de la columna "A" que tengan el valor 5. Pero al momento de ejecutar no me elimina ninguna fila que tenga el valor 5.

```
    Sub Borrar()
    Dim Fila As Long
    
    For Fila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(Fila, 1)) = 5 Then Cells(Fila, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next Fila
   End Sub
```

**Estos son los datos en el excel**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el problema cual es?

Comment: perdón, ya lo corregí, me olvidé poner cual era el problema

Comment: Claro, no estas comparando el valor de la celda, estas haciendo un count....

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ahora si ya me elimina los valores 5 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando lo que quieres borrar es siempre lo mismo, esta opción es mucho más rápida:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Borrar()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nombrehoja")
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, 5
        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
            .Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

filtras la columna en cuestión por el valor a borrar, compruebas que haya datos a partir de la fila 2 (si es que tus encabezados están  en la 1) y borras de golpe todas las filas que contienen el 5.